# Proving the intersection of an open set by induction

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to make sense of this question:

$S_n$ = $(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$,  $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Find $\cup_{n\geq1}S_n$,  $\cap_{n\geq1}S_n$, then use induction to show that $\cap_{1\leq k \leq n} = (-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$

I've already found $\cup_{n\geq1}S_n = S_1 = (-1,1)$ and  $\cap_{n\geq1}S_n=\emptyset$ .
However, I am unsure on how to go about doing the induction step for  $\cap_{1\leq k \leq n} = S_n =(-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider *accepting* the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

1. $\bigcap_{n\geq1}S_n=\emptyset$ is not true. We have $\bigcap_{n\geq1}S_n=\{0\}.$
2. $$\bigcap_{1\leq k \leq n+1}S_k = (\bigcap_{1\leq k \leq n}S_k) \cap S_{n+1} =S_n \cap S_{n+1}=S_{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\bigcap_{n\geq 1} S_n$ is actually not the empty set. There is a single number that is an element of $S_n$ for all $n$.

---

For the induction, take your time and go slowly. Remember, for induction, you have the following steps:

1. Take a statement $P(n)$.
2. Prove the statement $P(1)$.
3. Assume that the statement $P(n)$ is true *for some $n$.
4. Prove, from 3., that $P(n+1)$ is true.

Steps 3 and 4 can be rewritten into one step, i.e. "Prove that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ is true.

In your case, clearly, the statement $P(n)$ should be $P(n)="\bigcap_{1\leq k\leq n}S_k=\left(-\frac1n, \frac1n\right)$".

Now, it's time for the induction proof. Start slow:

1. Write down what $P(1)$ is. Can you prove this statement?
2. Write down what $P(n)$ is. Yes, again. Just do it. Trust me.
3. Directly below $P(n)$, write down what $P(n+1)$ is. Observe the two statements. Stare at them for a while. Try and figure out how you could prove $P(n+1)$ from $P(n)$.

**Hint** (for step 3 above):  $$\bigcap_{1\leq k\leq n+1} S_k= \bigcap_{1\leq k \leq n} S_k \cap S_{n+1}.$$